# how to make shortcut to Windows-CE application on Smart Device CAB Project?

Tags: windows-ce, setup-project

how to make shortcut to Windows-CE application on Smart Device CAB Project ?

i try this on my Smart Device CAB Project:

i open `Windows -> Desktop ->` and make the shortcut to my exe file

but no shortcut made

how to do it ?

Comment: The only way you can do it is to install the cab file in a location and from the .exe file installed on your windows ce device just click the icon > > send shortcut to desktop.

Comment: thanks for the help, but i need something that work Automatic

Answer (score 1):

Could the following be what you are looking for?
[Deploy a Desktop Shortcut to a Device running Windows CE 4.2 (VS2005)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/145440/deploy-a-desktop-shortcut-to-a-device-running-windows-ce-4-2-vs2005)