# How do I install an app onto Win Mobile 6.5 device so it appears on the desktop/start menu?

Tags: installation, cab, windows-mobile-6.5

I created a CAB project and the installer runs fine on my mobile device, but I have to go to the explorer and open "Program Files/My APP" to find the exe and launch it.

Is there some action I have to take in the config of the setup project or during install to make this work as I want?

**(I want to have the icon on the main window/desktop or start menu so that I can run it from there)**

Comment: Perhaps this will help:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/145440/deploy-a-desktop-shortcut-to-a-device-running-windows-ce-4-2-vs2005

Comment: Thanks Cosmin - though now I am even more confused.

Comment: Is there a simple example that explains what I have to do?

Comment: I don't think there is a simple solution for this, at least not a free one. You basically need to create the shortcut file yourself, configure it and then include it in your CAB. There are some commercial setup authoring tools which have direct support for this, but you would have to purchase a license.

Comment: OK, thanks - it is not clear to me what that file is or the contents.  The links either contain inconsistencies or they are just missing significant useful information.  SO I am a little stuck on how to proceed.

Comment: Just found this article: http://www.j2i.net/BlogEngine/post/2010/02/04/Windows-Phone-Deployment-Patterns-Part-0-of-n.aspx . It looks like you can just create a regular shortcut and configure it to install in "\Windows\Start Menu".

Comment: Thanks - that helped a lot.  Just have to test it and see now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[This is the link/answer that worked for me](http://www.j2i.net/BlogEngine/post/2010/02/04/Windows-Phone-Deployment-Patterns-Part-0-of-n.aspx) - from Cosmin Pirvu's comment above

> Just found this article: j2i.net/BlogEngine/post/2010/02/04/… . It
>   looks like you can just create a regular shortcut and configure it to
>   install in "\Windows\Start Menu". – Cosmin Pirvu Sep 9 at 13:35